# Recovery Menu on Fake Note3 China version

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-3

My colleague owns Faked Galaxy Note 3 from China with all the gifts - bloatware from Chinese market etc.  There is no root on the phone (I tried to check it with supersu/rom manager/uninstall) and the only option to get the root - probably to understand this "recovery" menu on Chinese:

[image]

UPD 
I've found that first line is related to factory:

[image]

I've found that first 3 options are related to test -

[image]

any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem with mine.  According to google this was the translation I was able to get from the menu choices.

- 自动测试

  - Automatic test
- 手动测试

  - Manual testing
- 单项测试

  - single test
- 测试报告

  - test report
- 调试测试项

  - debug test items
- 清除e MMC

  - clear e MMC
- 版本信

  - version of the letter (?) - gives bb chip, ms board, IMEI, barcode, etc
- 重启手机

  - reboot the phone

If you find out how to enter download mode or root this device please share.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-a3000/general/lenovo-3000-factory-mode-chinese-list-t2655858 - this thread gives the above info and also gives the sub-menu details. On my Acer E380 I used volume-down to get to the "reboot" option shown above and then pressed the power button to activate and as expected it rebooted the phone. Entering this mode was via power+volume-down for ~12s.